# Comparing fit of time series to true process

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, correlation, goodness-of-fit, similarities

I know that this question have been asked many times in this forum, but I am having troubles in understanding the correct approach to my aim.

I have several time series representing a growth process grouped by some factor. Each factor contains three time series: *S.true*, *S1*, and *S2*.
For each factor, I know that *S.true* is the true process while *S1* and *S2* are two simulations (deterministic) which aim at replicating the true growth.

What I'd like to do is to demonstrated that *S1* is a more accurate representation of *S.true* compared to *S2*. I was thinking of using a variance test, in which I demonstrate that *S1* is closer to *S.true* than *S2*. I am not sure whether this is the correct way to approach the problem.

Example of time series:
[image]

Comment: If you want to know whether the model is a good fit for the observed data, why would you only generate one simulated series? You could generate many, say 200 (if you want to do plots, too many may obscure things by overplotting but you want to have enough to properly assess variation) and plot them to see whether the real series looks atypical. (A formal test with p-values can be defined by looking at the empirical distribution of any test statistic you could be interested in here.)

Comment: The first thing to look for would be a formal test without simulation for the specific model that you use (obviously without knowing the model we can't know whether such test exists). This would *not* regard pairs of real and simulated series but would only test whether the real series is compatible with the model, which seems to be what you're really interested in.

Comment: Hi @ChristianHennig, thanks for your answer. 
The model has no variation in it, so simulating it many times would be useless as I would obtain 200 times the exact same values. 
I am not really understanding the second part of your answer though. What you mean by formal test without simulation? The model is an ODE simulating the process of growth observed in the experiments.

Comment: OK, I thought it was probabilistic. But then, if it's deterministic without probabilistic component, I don't see how any statistical test can apply, as these all are based on modelling a random variation that doesn't seem to exist in your model. The question of a "good fit" in my view is then rather how much deviation in practice can be tolerated, which is not for a statistical test to answer.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I understand what you mean. I am looking at some correlation value instead, such as cointegration or cross-correlation (since I have autocorrelation within each vector. I was just wondering whether there could be other measures of goodness of fit.